# Grails 2 'order' criteria not working in unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, grails, grails-2.0, hibernate-criteria

I'm using grails 2.1.0 and groovy 1.8. I have the following code in a service:

```
def listServerPartners() {
    ServerModel.withCriteria {
        partner {
            order('name', 'asc')
        }
        projections {
            distinct('partner')
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine for both the running application and integration tests. However, when I try to use with unit tests, I get a blank list as a result.

I noticed that if I changed the above code to the code below and implement the **comparable** interface in the object partner, the unit tests work, but then the application and integration tests don't.

```
def listServerPartners() {
    ServerModel.withCriteria {
        projections {
            distinct('partner')
        }
        order('partner', 'asc')
    }
}
```

Looking at the SQL when running the application, I notice that for the first code, I get a

```
"order by partner_al1_.PartnerName asc"
```

and for the second one, I get a

```
"order by partner_al1_.Partner_Id asc"
```

, what is obviously what I don't want.

Any suggestions about how to mock the correctly behavior that I have when running the application and integration tests for the unit tests?

**Updated: Output from Unit test:**

```
assert Partner.list() == results
               |      |  |
               |      |  []
               |      false
               [Partner 4, Partner 3, Partner 2, Partner 1]
```

-- Thanks

Comment: Just FYI: This [was a bug](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-8229?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:changehistory-tabpanel) until the RC2. So i wonder why you still have this issue..

Comment: ..and, [as I found right now](http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-8861), in the 2.0.4 version as well.

Comment: The problem is not the projections block. I have the same problem with other criteria queries that don't use projections. The problem I believe is in the order statement itself. Maybe a bug in the mock implementation?

Comment: did you try the second version with order('partner.name', 'asc') ?

Comment: I just tried. When running the unit test I get **groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: partner.name**

Answer (score 0):

I updated PlasticCriteria plugin. Now it works with this:

```
def a = new Artist(name: 'Andreas Achenbach').save()
def c = new Artist(name: 'Constance Gordon-Cumming').save()
def b = new Artist(name: 'Botero').save()
new Portrait(artist: a, name: "Clearing Up—Coast of Sicily").save()
new Portrait(artist: c, name: "Indian Life at Mirror Lake").save()
new Portrait(artist: c, name: "Temporary Chimneys and Fire Fountains").save()
new Portrait(artist: b, name: "Botero's Cat").save()
def artistList = Portrait.withCriteria{
    artist{
        order('name', 'asc')
    }
    projections{
        artist{
            distinct('name')
        }
    }
}
assert ['Andreas Achenbach', 'Botero', 'Constance Gordon-Cumming'] == artistList
```

May help you
https://github.com/fabiooshiro/plastic-criteria

If I change projections to:

```
projections{ distinct('artist') }
```

I got this integration error: "ARTIST_ALI1_.NAME" must be in the result list in this case

But works in unit tests.